# How to wait the response to the innermost firebase function?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase function for reading a data in Redux action. The problem is that function did not wait to response of Firebase function. You can see the all codes of function below. How can I set that second firebase function wait the response?

```
export const getSelectedGroupDetail = groupUid => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: GET_SELECTED_GROUP_DETAIL_START,
  });
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref('/groups/' + groupUid)
    .once('value')
    .then(function (snapshot) {
      const membersList = _.map(snapshot.val().members, (val, uid) => ({ ...val, uid }));

      let groupMembersList = _.map(selectedGroupData.members, (val, uid) => {
    return { ...val, uid };
  });
      for (let index = 0; index < groupMembersList.length; index++) {
        firebase.database().ref('/users/' + groupMembersList[index].uid).once('value')
          .then(function (snapshot) {
            let name = snapshot.val().displayName;
            groupMembersList[index] = { ...groupMembersList[index], name };
          })
    .catch(e => console.log(e.message));
      }

      const yeniGrupDetayi = { ...snapshot.val(), uid: groupUid, membersList };
      console.log('ACTION NE YAZDI ? ===>', yeniGrupDetayi);
      dispatch({
        type: GET_SELECTED_GROUP_DETAIL_SUCCESS,
        payload: yeniGrupDetayi,
      });
      NavigationService.navigate('GroupDetail');
    })
    .catch(e => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_SELECTED_GROUP_DETAIL_FAIL,
      });
      Alert.alert('Hata', 'Beklenmedik bir hata meydana geldi.');
    });
};
```

If the 2nd Firebase function will wait the response, `memberList` will be inside `yeniGrupDetayi` object. If the 2nd Firebase function will wait the response, `membersList` will be inside `yeniGrupDetayi` object. At the end of action code, FlatList is running, but I couldn't see `membersList` in FlatList.

Comment: Do you want your program to wait for `firebase.database().ref('/users/' + groupMembersList[index].uid).once('value')` line to execute?

Comment: @AsimHashmi Yes sir.

Comment: Just put your code in the .then() of the firebase call you're waiting for

Comment: After a long time I noticed a problem. Some of the objects in the Array do not take the "name" key. The first data that is strange is the name, the next 5 data is missing, then there is again. All the same. You can see the problem in the photo on the link. What's the reason?

https://ibb.co/SJvBhb6
https://ibb.co/jvDFq2k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you make multiple promises call through your loop, and you put separate code after your loop. Problem is, code doesn't wait to be executed until you precise it.

So either you regroup your calls in a single promise and wait for all of them to respond, either you do something like this:

```
export const getSelectedGroupDetail = groupUid => dispatch => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_SELECTED_GROUP_DETAIL_START,
      });
  firebase
      .database()
      .ref('/groups/' + groupUid)
      .once('value')
      .then(function (snapshot) {
        const membersList = _.map(snapshot.val().members, (val, uid) => ({ ...val, uid }));

        let groupMembersList = _.map(selectedGroupData.members, (val, uid) => {
          return { ...val, uid };
        });
        for (let index = 0; index < groupMembersList.length; index++) {
          firebase.database().ref('/users/' + groupMembersList[index].uid).once('value')
              .then(function (childSnapshot) {
                let name = childSnapshot.val().displayName;
                groupMembersList[index] = { ...groupMembersList[index], name };

                if(index === groupMembersList.length -1)
                {
                  const yeniGrupDetayi = { ...snapshot.val(), uid: groupUid, membersList };
                  console.log('ACTION NE YAZDI ? ===>', yeniGrupDetayi);
                  dispatch({
                    type: GET_SELECTED_GROUP_DETAIL_SUCCESS,
                    payload: yeniGrupDetayi,
                  });
                  NavigationService.navigate('GroupDetail');
                }
              })
              .catch(e => console.log(e.message));
        }
      })
      .catch(e => {
        dispatch({
          type: GET_SELECTED_GROUP_DETAIL_FAIL,
        });
        Alert.alert('Hata', 'Beklenmedik bir hata meydana geldi.');
      });
};
```

It is kind of messy and not very maintainable but will do the trick

Comment: After a long time I noticed a problem. Some of the objects in the Array do not take the "name" key. The first data that is strange is the name, the next 5 data is missing, then there is again. All the same. You can see the problem in the photo on the link. What's the reason?

Screen SS - https://ibb.co/SJvBhb6 | Debug SS - https://ibb.co/jvDFq2k

Comment: Are you sure name is stored correctly in firebase ?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract your

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/' + groupMembersList[index].uid).once('value')
```

line to a function like this:

```
async function getMembersListFromDB() {
  return firebase.database().ref('/users/' + groupMembersList[index].uid).once('value')
}
```

Now in your for loop:

```
for (let index = 0; index < groupMembersList.length; index++) {
  await this.getMembersListFromDB().then(function (snapshot) {
    let name = snapshot.val().displayName;
    groupMembersList[index] = { ...groupMembersList[index], name };
  })
```

**Explanation:**

You can use `aysnc` with combination of `await` to pause the execution of program untill `Promise` is resolved. The `await` keyword will tell the program to wait for the database query to execute and then the program will continue its execution

More on async/await  [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: Sir, thank you so much for your effort. But, Program gave an error that is "you cant use 'await' keyword outside async function". Can you edit your post? Also, can you edit my full of codes?

Comment: Why do you use async ? the firebase functions are already promises.
Just use .then().catch like you would do with a promise

Comment: hello hardworker, you are right but how should i edit my codes? can you support me about it?